# How can I make a simple vowel counter method in Java?

Tags: java, counter

Here's my method:

```
public char[] ReturnAllVowels(String word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word.contains("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"))     
        {

        }
    }        
}
```

It says that || cannot be applied to String class. How can I do this then?

Comment: Your method name should be lowercase (`returnAllVowels`) in Java. Your question says that you want to get the `vowel counter`, but your function returns `char[]`. Do you want a counter or do you want to get the actual vowels contained?

Comment: The actual vowels contained, and I don't really have to start with lowercase. That's just a matter of taste. Everyone has their own way of writing.

Comment: Taste is something like choosing to put opening braces on a new line, your job is to make code that people can understand, uppercase at the beginning of an identifier usually indicates (in Java) a class name rather than a method name.

Comment: Also singe starting with a lowercase is an age-old convention, there's a lot of especially reflection based tools which *may* break if you don't follow the said convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char ch = word.charAt (i);
if (ch == 'a' || ch=='e') {

}
```

Comment: Hey, minusers, leave comments at least.

Answer (score 12):

Using regular expressions you can try.

```
int count = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String regex = "[aeiou]";               
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);   
    int vowelcount = 0;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    while (m.find()) {
      vowelcount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total vowels: " + vowelcount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Peter's code to get the vowels.

```
char[] vowels = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    // TODO code application logic here
    String s;
    //String vowels = a;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = in.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
        char v = s.charAt(i);
        if(v=='a' || v=='e' || v=='i' || v=='o' || v=='u' || v=='A' || v=='E' || v=='I' || v=='O' || v=='U'){
            System.out.print (v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would have done using `Scanner`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userInput;
    int vowelA = 0, vowelE = 0, vowelI = 0, vowelO = 0, vowelU = 0; 

    System.out.println(welcomeMessage);
    userInput = scan.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    for(int x = 0; x <= userInput.length() - 1; x++) {
        if(userInput.charAt(x) == 97)
            vowelA++;
        else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 101)
            vowelE++;
        else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 105)
            vowelI++;
        else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 111)
            vowelO++;
        else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 117)
            vowelU++;   
    } 

    System.out.println("There were " + vowelA + " A's in your sentence.");
    System.out.println("There were " + vowelE + " E's in your sentence.");
    System.out.println("There were " + vowelI + " I's in your sentence.");
    System.out.println("There were " + vowelO + " O's in your sentence.");
    System.out.println("There were " + vowelU + " U's in your sentence.");
}
```