# Count vowels in a word

Tags: java, regex, character

I need to find count of the vowels in a word. However, when I compare the letters in the word whether they are vowel or not,

For example, what I do is like the one below,

`if( word[i] == 'a' || word[i] == 'e' || word[i] == 'i' || word[i] == 'u'` ...... ) //the rest is omitted

the `if` statement gets too long. Is there a way to compare them with a regex or regex-like comparison and give me the number of vowel occurrences in a string?

Comment: what you actually want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find all vowels

```
String line = "Ahis order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "(?i)[aeiou]";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0) );
}
```

If you want to find number of times they occur you can use `replace` like

```
String line = "Ahis order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "(?i)[aeiou]";
System.out.println(line.replaceAll(pattern, "").length());
```

**NOTE** :- `(?i)` is inline modifier which indicates whatever pattern follows it will be case insensitive

Comment: Will the replaceAll method change the original text or will it give only in case of a replace, the number of occurrences would be that number?

Comment: @drJava if you want to replace original string you can use `line = line.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "")`

Comment: No, I do not want. The original text should stay same. Your answer is correct but I can accept it in 5 minutes as a correct answer :) Stackoverflow things.

Answer (score 4):

### Approch 1:

If you want count vowel Using regular expressions you can try.

```
int count = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length();
```

### Approch 2:

first count the word length and then used this

```
word = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length();
```

and subtract from the Original word.you will get the count of vowels.

Comment: And what's different/better to rock's answer? This just looks like a [copy of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2077470/5527985).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer, although a little inefficient than the other:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    String inputup=input.toUpperCase();
    int vowel=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=inputup.length()-1;i++) {
        char ch=inputup.charAt(i);
        if((ch=='A')||(ch=='E')||(ch=='I')||(ch=='O')||(ch=='U')) {
            vowel++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No. of Vowels="+vowel);
}
```

}